# Formic acid and carbon monoxide outgassing from latex mattress

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, safety, materials

Formic acid is used as a coagulant to turn rubber tree sap into latex, formic acid also decomposes to carbon monoxide. Does this mean things like latex mattresses have the potential to off-gas carbon monoxide? I am assuming they don't, but I have had carbon monoxide poisoning twice, so I would like to buy a latex mattress and I don't need $\ce{CO}$ issues for the third time.

If this isn't an appropriate forum for this question and you can point me in the direction of one that is that would be great.

Comment: I see a few possible issues with this reasoning. 1) assuming that formic acid is used in the production of latex, is that specific type of latex used for mattresses? And if so, does it still contain any formic acid? Many toxic chemicals are used in the manufacture of certain products, but that does not mean that the products still contain them. The manufacturing process may include steps during which the acid is removed. That is easily checked by looking at the specification of mattress latex. My guess is that they will not allow much formic acid to be in there.

Comment: 2) assume that a latex mattress contains formic acid. Formic acid can indeed decompose to CO, but only under very strenuous conditions or in the presence of catalysts. See [this article](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j150262a003). So the question would be: how fast is CO produced? If very fast, then CO would probably be gone before the mattress reaches the customer. If very slowly, then CO would probably not reach dangerous concentrations during normal use.

Comment: 3) formic acid is quite volatile (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid)), so it might actually evaporate before decomposing. 4) CO poisoning in a domestic environment is usually associated with the use of faulty heating equipment. If that is what happened in your case (BTW, sorry to hear that!) perhaps I would advise to check that before going for less obvious options. Having said all that, I once bought a latex mattress, it was plastic-wrapped, and when I unwrapped it at home it smelled so bad I had to air it for 2 weeks before it was bearable! But CO is odourless :)